# Why is the derivative of the complex definition of sin(x) equal to icos(x)?

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers

Using $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2}$, $\frac{d}{dx} \sin x = i\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}=i\cos x$, not $\cos x$. Why is this?

Comment: @metamorphy oh of course. That was stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The equation for $\sin$ should be $$\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2\color{red}i}.$$

Comment: $$\sin x=\dfrac {(\cos x+i\sin x)-(\cos x-i\sin x)}{2i}$$